# C# TreeView Collapse/Expand on parent select

Tags: c#, treeview

This one is hard to explain so i will just tell you what i want to achieve and how i am doing it so maybe someone witll have an idea on what i am doing wrong.

In my winForm i have a TreeView control that i populate. All parents have children (any number of them) but no children have children of their own. Example:

```
- Parent 1
        Child 1
        Child 2
        Child 3
- Parent 2
       Child 4
```

The behaviour i want is the following:

1. when the user clicks a child it get's selected (done by default)
2. When the user clicks a parent, it should either collapse or expand but not change any selection

Point 1 is no problem as it is the default behaviour of a TreeView, Point 2 however is another story.

Here is what i have done so far:

To prevent the parent from being selected i add a BeforeSelect event handler and put in it the following code:

```
if (e.Node.Parent == null)
    e.Cancel = true;
```

This does the job perfectly. So now that i canceled the selection of the parent i want to expand or collapse it. So i changed the above code to:

```
if (e.Node.Parent == null)
{
    if (e.Node.IsExpanded)
    {
        e.Node.Collapse();
    }
    else
    {
        e.Node.Expand();
    }
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

This somewhat works - except that, unlike clicking the + sign, calling Expand() or Collapse() makes the parent node be selected, ignoring the e.Cancel = true; line.

I tried getting the SelectedNode before i call Collapse() or Expand() and then setting it back - it works but when i do that it will expand the parent again to make the selection.

Somewhow the + sign does exactly what i want to happen when i click on a parent - i just can't seem to get it to work.

Ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    private bool allowExpandCollapse = false;

    private void treeView1_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = !allowExpandCollapse;
    }

    private void treeView1_BeforeCollapse(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = !allowExpandCollapse;
    }

    private void treeView1_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Parent == null)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }

    private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Parent == null)
        {
            allowExpandCollapse = true;
            if (e.Node.IsExpanded)
            {
                TreeNode selectedNode = treeView1.SelectedNode;
                e.Node.Collapse();
                allowExpandCollapse = false;
                treeView1.SelectedNode = selectedNode;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Node.Expand();
                allowExpandCollapse = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Way to resurrect na old thread - lol - i have since moved off this project but your answer seems solid so i will give it to you

Comment: @chiper Can you explain more about what's going on here? I'm not entirely sure. My problem is that my SelectedNodeChanged doesn't fire if I click on the same node twice (one for expand, one for collapse)

Comment: I didn't find SelectedNodeChanged event in TreeView. Did you mean AfterSelect? Actually, this code does not change selection when you click on some root (expandable) node. Please note that the structure of your tree should follow the statement from question: "All parents have children (any number of them) but no children have children of their own"