# How to set .NET TreeView nodes to expand when text is clicked - C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, nodes

I have a TreeView in a master page that toggles nodes between expanded and collapsed when the +/- is clicked and collapses all the other nodes when the current node is expanded. I am trying to have it follow the same behavior when the text of the node is clicked. When the node text is clicked it does collapse all the other nodes and goes to the page the node is linked to, but it does not expand the current node. I have tried numerous solutions from other similar questions but none have worked. Here is my C# code behind for the TreeView events.

```
protected void MainMenu_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainMenu.CollapseAll();
    TreeNode node = MainMenu.SelectedNode;
    node.Expand();
    while (node.Parent != null)
    {
        node = node.Parent;
        node.Expand();
    }
}

protected void MainMenu_TreeNodeExpanded(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node.Parent == null) return;
    string strNodeValue = e.Node.Value;
    foreach (TreeNode node in e.Node.Parent.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (node.Value != strNodeValue)
            node.CollapseAll();
    }
}


protected void MainMenu_TreeNodeDataBound(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    e.Node.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.SelectExpand;
}
```

I appreciate all ideas and suggestions.

Comment: Tell me if [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126873/c-sharp-treeview-collapse-expand-on-parent-select) helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think that is for a WindowsForm and not aspx pages. I did try using the NodeMouseClick, MouseClick, Before and After events to make it expand but with no success :-/